# Error while executing awk command in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to print the memory details . Total , Free and used memory using a shell script. This is my code -

```
printf "\nSystem Details\n"
printf "CPU $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | head -1)" 

printf "Total Memory:"
printf "$(awk '/^Mem/ {print $3}' <(free -m))"
```

But terminal doesn't display any memory details. It shows this error.

```
Memory:info.sh: command substitution: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `('
info.sh: command substitution: line 23: `awk '/^Mem/ {print $3}' <(free -m))"'
```

Comment: check awk is available by running this in your cli . awk 'BEGIN{ print 1}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run the line in question under `bash`:

```
$ printf "$(awk '/^Mem/ {print $3}' <(free -m))"
5603$
```

It works.  Now let's try it under `dash`:

```
$ printf "$(awk '/^Mem/ {print $3}' <(free -m))"
dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Now, we see the syntax error about the unexpected `(`.  The error is because `dash` does not support `process substitution`.

If you want to run under `dash` or similar shells, the solution is to use a pipeline instead:

```
$ printf "$(free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $3}')"
5623$
```

*Process substitution* is supported by bash, zsh, Ksh88, ksh93, but not pdksh, mksh, or dash.  The pipeline approach should be supported by all POSIX shells.

#### Improvement

The above works as long as the output does not contain printf-active characters.  It is much better practice to use an explicit format string and thereby avoid unpleasant surprises:

```
printf "%s" "$(free -m | awk '/^Mem/{print $3}')"
```

Comment: @EdMorton Very true.  Added to answer.